# Looking for a REGEXP to swap two words

Tags: regex, visual-studio, swap

String ex. `something.text = obj.something` I am looking for a REGEXP that will swap the first value before the '=' with the second resulting in: `obj.something = something.text`

I understand most Regular Expressions are quite universal but to be specific I plan to use this statement semi frequently in Visual Studio.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good thing you specified the flavor.  *Most* regex flavors are similar to each other, but not Visual Studio's.  Its syntax is very, very different from most other flavors.  Try this:

search: `{:w\.something} = {something\.:w}`

replace `\2 = \1`

`{...}` forms a "tagged expression" (known to the rest of the world as a "capturing group")

`:w` matches one or more letters

Here's a [complete reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Splendid answer! I was unaware VS was different from most, however I did suspect as much.